# Server keeps disconnecting!! Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, controller, nodes

can someone help me out please?

Keep getting this error. I read that it most commonly appears when you try to send the response twice, but I can't find which one is the one doing that. I assume the fault is inside the Controller. It doesn't affect the functionality too much, although I did have to edit out some commands as they were preventing the pages responsible from loading altogether ever since this error started appearing, and it does disconnect me from the server as soon as I refresh or change pages.

The full error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:558
throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/__/Desktop/__/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:8)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/Users/__/Desktop/__/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:599:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/__/Desktop/__/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:145:14)
    at done (/Users/__/Desktop/__/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1009:10)
    at /Users/__/Desktop/__/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:196:5
    at /Users/__/Desktop/__/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:153:10
    at /Users/__/Desktop/__/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:135:11
    at loadAllPartials (/Users/__/Desktop/__/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:91:10)
    at /Users/__/Desktop/__/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:119:10 {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

The Controller:

```
const goalPlannerDAO = require('../models/plannerModels.js');
const db = new goalPlannerDAO();
db.init();

exports.landing_page = function(req, res) {
    res.render('planner',   {
        'title' : 'Goal Planner',
        'planner': [     {
                'user': 'John',
                'typeOfExercise' : 'Yoga',
                'goalDate' : '2020-12-01',
                'exerciseDuration' : '1 Hour',
                'goalStatus' : 'COMPLETE'

}, 
{
                'user': 'John',
                'typeOfExercise' : 'Football',
                'goalDate' : '2020-12-02',
                'exerciseDuration' : '2 Hours',
                'goalStatus' : 'COMPLETE'

},
{
                'user': 'John',
                'typeOfExercise' : 'Weightlifting',
                'goalDate' : '2020-12-03',
                'exerciseDuration' : '1 Hour 30 Minutes',
                'goalStatus' : 'INCOMPLETE'

}]
});

db.getAllGoals().then((list) => {
    res.render('planner', {
        'title': 'Goal Planner',
        'planner': list
    });
    console.log('promise resolved');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('promise rejected', err);
}) 

db.removeGoal(req.body.user);
}

exports.post_new_goal = function(req, res) {
    console.log('processing post-new_entry controller');
    if (!req.body.typeOfExercise) {
        res.status(400).send("Entries must have a type of exercise.");
        return;
}
    db.addGoal(req.body.user, req.body.typeOfExercise, req.body.goalDate, req.body.exerciseDuration);
    return;
}

exports.show_new_goals = function(req, res) {
    res.render('newGoal', {
        'title': 'New Goal'
    })
}

exports.server_error = function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500);
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.send('Internal Server Error.');
}
```

Thank you!